# Change mouse scroll to not zoom in Expression Blend?

Tags: scroll, mouse, expression-blend, zooming

Is there a way to change the mouse wheel behavour in Expression Blend?

I want it to scroll instead of zoom.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Tools>Options>Artboard

Change "Zoom by using" to Ctrl "+ mouse wheel"

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft has moved the setting. In Blend for VS 2015 it’s under Tools>Options, XAML Designer>General.